# Only allowing some enums in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I suppose this has been asked before but I am having trouble phrasing it to find a solutions so apologies in advance.

I have an enum type:

```
enum Events {
 FOO = 'foo',
 BAR = 'bar'
}
```

I have a function that in turn accepts a function. The function it accepts has a type `EventHandler`

```
export const wrapEventFn = async (fn: EventHandler): Promise<unknown> => {
...
```

The type definition for `EventHandler` is:

```
type EventHandler = (event: Events) => Promise<void>
```

Now the functions that I pass are themselves limited in what events they can handle. For example:

```
export const actionHandler = async (
  event: Events.FOO
): Promise<void> => {...
```

Doing the above does not work and TS yields error:

```
wrapEventFn(actionHandler) // actionHandler is underlined w error
```

Error

```
Argument of type '(event: Events.FOO) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'Events' is not assignable to type
```

How can I fix this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAogbqALgZygbwFBQGIHldQC8UA5AGYD2FJANFgEICCASkaQEYCGATiRgL4YMiAJ4AHYLAQhEACU4gAJgBtg3NgApg0xAC4pSZAEoiAPigAFbhQgBLZMAA8cCrcWmA3EMXAAxsp5JMjAQX0RbChAoAHduTjF4JGwQDTIQfUSZeSVVbiN9Kxt7JxCAaxAKaJBPbz8A7iCQsIiozmbI7JU1LR0MnWQAOjxcfMtrOwdnV3cvDFj4zMRkjTbwjoUuvI8gA)

Comment: `(event: Events.FOO): Promise<void>` can't handle any of `Events` but only the specific one - hence the error

Comment: Could you add some more info on what `wrapEventFn` does?

Comment: PLease take a look on this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21998

Comment: The error is completely correct. Your `actionHandler` is handling only one of the possible `Events`, but the definition of `EventHandler` suggests that it can be called with any `Event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `enum`, use [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types)

```
type Events = 'foo' | 'bar'
```

Now make EventHandler take a generic object that is assignable to type `Events`:

```
type EventHandler<T extends Events> = (event: T) => Promise<void>;

declare function wrapEventFn<T extends Events>(fn: EventHandler<T>): Promise<unknown>;
```

Now we can create your type which is a known subset of the available events:

```
type SpecializedEvents = 'foo'; 
declare function actionHandler(event: SpecializedEvents): Promise<void>;
```

Now we can call it like so:

```
wrapEventFn<SpecializedEvents>(actionHandler);
```

As it turns out, we don't even need to state the generic type, the typescript compiler can infer it. It's much more readable to just write this:

```
wrapEventFn(actionHandler);
```

To demonstrate this works, we can attempt to pass an incompatible type in:

```
type CompletelyTheWrongType = 'this' | 'is' | 'wrong';
declare function wrongActionHandler(event: CompletelyTheWrongType): Promise<void>;


wrapEventFn(wrongActionHandler);
```

The error this produces reads as follows:

> Arguments of type '(event: CompletelyTheWrongType) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventHandler'...

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA5AMwPZ5ZQA+2ARgIYBOWA3AFD2iSwLIASFiAJgDYRUAPABUoEAB7Ak3NPCSoAfBigAKCG2AAuKMICUGJQAUqeALYBLFBEFw857gob1uEAMa9q0HAFdEr4OZ4iFAA7lQUYHLIAGKIImKS0rIaKAoqOIjaUcCcPPxCwgq62sZmlta+ANaIeCGIjoxM4NAAypCu5hS85gBeENzZaJgw4u7eLoKDADTk1FgNLu6eUD5+AUFQFP6BiLl8Amoa2m1und19AynFUKUWVjZ2Dk6NYRHZsYInHV29-YNpW3Wuy4+yougYr0iGliKkBOz2+XBjQA9MioABNPDeKAACwobCwwCgUhQUm4xJx0GY0BQIFJEFM9FRUF8AV4UBAWKwCCgAHM8MApMFzETgHgVh5eVAUGYIMAceZEFLzLx+LyugBCJosADCZjA-CkvBAwkpAHUTErhM1lISFSgiKQsJZHdgwkFeXRnG4PFQvL5tht3UqAIKB4F5A7qeTaPWmA1yiDG00QC0e62Qa63coPewNRiQ96IFTB3lhoEIgTgoA)